# Script for running terminal command in ubuntu

Tags: command-line, scripts, matlab

I am using MATLAB from my college network which has a limited number of users. So whenever I type `matlab` in terminal if the user limit is exceeded, then it shows errors: "user limit exceeded", and now I have to try again and again. I want to write a script that opens terminal and writes 'matlab' into it and if it opens then stop else keep on running.

Answer (score 0):

```sh
#!/bin/sh

while [ matlab | grep -q 'user limit exceeded' ]
do
   matlab
   echo "Trying again"
done
echo "Success!"
```

That *should* do it.